# How to prove that $a_n\le 1.51^{2^n}$ for the sequence $a_0 = 1; a_n=a_{n-1}^2 + 1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I have tried induction, but it doesn't seem to work:

$a_n = a_{n-1}^2 + 1 \le \left(1.51^{2^{n-1}}\right)^2+1 = 1.51^{2^n}+1$.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Try showing inductively something like $a_n \le \lambda 1.51^{2^n}$ for some $\lambda < 1$. Note that $\lambda^2 t + 1 \le \lambda t$ for all $t$ sufficiently large; you have to choose $\lambda$ such that the $n=0$ (or some other small $n$ so you can check directly all the cases you need to) case is 'sufficiently large'.

Comment: This cannot work for $n=0$ as $a_0=1=1.51^{2^0}$. Do you mean to show it separately for $n=0$ and start the induction from $n=1$?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean. It doesn't have to work for all $n$. You can start at $n=1$ or $n=2$ instead, and check by hand $a_1\le 1.51^2$ and $a_2\le 1.51^4$.

Comment: I'm not certain that's the easiest way to do it, but it is something to try

Comment: @DarkMalthorp - that sounds promising, I will try that. Thanks!

Comment: I think it might be easier to show that $a_n<(1.51)^{2^n}-1$ (at least for large enough $n$).

Comment: @lulu that looks easier. I think my method you might have to go up to $n=4$ which is a lot of cases to check by hand.

Comment: @DarkMalthorp  Right. At $n=3$ I'm already clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's prove a stronger statement:

$$a_n\le 1.51^{2^n}-1\tag{1}$$

...for $n\ge4$.

Initial step: $a_0=1,a_1=2,a_2=5,a_3=26,a_4=677$. And $1.51^{2^4}-1=729.52$. So the statement is true for $n=4$.

Induction step: Suppose that $a_n\le 1.51^{2^n}-1$. It means that:

$$a_{n+1}=a_n^2+1$$

$$a_{n+1}\le (1.51^{2^n}-1)^2+1$$

$$a_{n+1}\le 1.51^{2^{n+1}}-2\times1.51^{2^n}+2$$

$$a_{n+1}\le 1.51^{2^{n+1}}-2(1.51^{2^n}-1)\tag{2}$$

Notice that:

$$2(1.51^{2^n}-1)\gt2(1.51-1)\gt 1\tag{3}$$

By combining (2) and (3) you get:

$$a_{n+1}\le 1.51^{2^{n+1}}-1$$

...which completes the induction step. So the statement (1) is defintely true and a weaker statement:

$$a_n\le 1.51^{2^n}$$

...is also true for $n\ge 4$.Manual check shows that it's also true for $n=0,1,2,3$ which completes the proof.

Answer (score 2):

For
$a_n 
= a_{n-1}^2 + 1
$,
suppose
$a_n
\le uv^{2^n}-1
$.
We will try to determine
$u$ and $v$
so that
$a_{n+1}
\le uv^{2^{n+1}}-1
$.

$\begin{array}\\
a_{n+1}
&= a_{n-1}^2 + 1\\
&\le (uv^{2^{n}}-1)^2 + 1\\
&= u^2v^{2^{n+1}}-2uv^{2^{n}}+1 + 1\\
&= u^2v^{2^{n+1}}-2uv^{2^{n}}+2\\
\end{array}
$

so we want
$u^2v^{2^{n+1}}-2uv^{2^{n}}+2
\le uv^{2^{n+1}}-1
$
or
$u(u-1)v^{2^{n+1}}
\le 2uv^{2^{n}}-3
$.

If
$u=1$ this is
$2v^{2^{n}}
\ge 3
$
or
$v^{2^{n}}
\ge \dfrac32
$
and this will certainly be true for
$v \ge \dfrac32$.

Therefore the induction step
will work
for any $v \ge \dfrac32$
if the induction hypothesis
is true.

As shown in Oldboy's answer,
this is true for
$v = 1.51$,
so that
this $v$ works.

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't seem too helpful. The induction hypothesis is not true for any $v\ge \frac{3}{2}$ (e.g., it doesn't work for $v= \frac{3}{2}$).

Comment: What I showed was that *if* the induction hypothesis is true for some $v \ge 3/2$ then it is true for all subsequent $n$.